# Play audio live stream on Samsung tizen

Tags: javascript, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, smart-tv

Looking for the best way to play Audio live stream such as http://radiocast-rr-d.vidnt.com/ipbc_IPBC80-90LA
On Samsung Tizen TV.

I tried some ways the best way was with JW Player and the streaming load very slow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Samsung's example content is quite thorough. Have a look here:

https://developer.tizen.org/development/training/native-application/creating-applications-multimedia/audio-playback-and-recording
https://developer.tizen.org/development/sample/native/Multimedia

The file you supplied is aac so it should play fine.

From memory you should also be able to use the HTML5 audio tag:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="xxx.aac" type="audio/aac">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's Samsung Product API: AVPlay

You may check this one,
This Guide shares how an application can play media content using the AVPlay API:

[Using AVPlay Guide](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/multimedia/media-playback/using-avplay/)

[AVPlay API References](http://%20developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/api-references/samsung-product-api-references/avplay-api/#)

Answer (score 0):

you might try using NexPlayer, it has a very nice streaming performance for Tizen TV apps!

https://github.com/NexPlayer/TizenWebOS

https://www.nexplayersdk.com/tizen-player/